# What is the correct syntax to use the logical OR operator with mutiple conditions in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to PHP. My question is, how do I use OR logic when I have parentheses? I have the following line of code:

```
if (get_option('nl_heading_font') === "Alegreya Sans") {
//do something
}
```

Id like to add:

```
if (get_option('nl_body_font') === "Alegreya Sans") {
//do something
}
```

Can I do this:

```
if (get_option('nl_body_font' || 'nl_heading_font') === "Alegreya Sans") {
//do something
}
```

Or

```
if (get_option('nl_body_font') === "Alegreya Sans") || (get_option('nl_heading_font') === "Alegreya Sans") {
//do something
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with executing the code you've just written and see the results yourself?

Comment: What was the error you receive when you execute the last code?

Comment: You can also use the `or` keyword.  `if (get_option('nl_body_font') === "Alegreya Sans" or get_option('nl_heading_font') === "Alegreya Sans")`

Comment: @JakeGould that could be a matter of debate. What does _"demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"_ mean? In my opinion, one knows how to do basic debugging, which means reducing the problem to few lines of code (what OP did) and (with full error reporting) run them and try to solve them (what OP didn't do). If OP had, he/she had found out that the last piece of code had worked, after removing the `(` that is too much

Comment: @kingkero This question might be useful for someone else in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, the best option is this. But you need to add extra parenthesis for the `OR`/`||` clause like so:

```
if ((get_option('nl_body_font') === "Alegreya Sans") || (get_option('nl_heading_font') === "Alegreya Sans")) {
//do something
}
```

The construct of `if()` requires it’s own parentheses.  So if you want to nest more conditions, you need to add more parentheses.  But looking at your code you can probably remove the extra parentheses around each clause & it would be fine:

```
if (get_option('nl_body_font') === "Alegreya Sans" || get_option('nl_heading_font') === "Alegreya Sans") {
//do something
}
```

But will all that said, looking at your logic better way to handle this is to use an array. So your code would be like this:

```
$nl_body_font_array = array('nl_body_font', 'nl_heading_font');
foreach ($nl_body_font_array as $nl_body_font_value) {
  if (get_option($nl_body_font_value) === "Alegreya Sans")) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

This way, you simple create an array with as many values as you want and just push them through the `if` logic via a loop. Easier to read & debug as your codebase grows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the php or format

```
if((/// your check condition) || (/// your check condition) || (/// your check condition) ){

/// Your Working code Here////////
}
```